# Использование значений переменных в коде программы Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, стало интересно, есть ли возможность использования значения переменных в коде программы? 
Самые банальные примеры:

- Вводим с клавиатуры строку, например, `+` или любой другой знак операции. Необходимо провести операцию, `знак` которой был введён с клавиатуры, и вывести результат на экран. (Без использования `switch-case` и любых других циклов)
- У нас есть несколько переменных, допустим, их имена - `foo_1`, `foo_2`, ..., `foo_10`. С клавиатуры вводится число `n`. Нужно вывести на экран значение переменной *foo_*`n`. Опять же без `switch-case` и подобных методов.

  Возможно, это глупость, но меня давно интересует этот вопрос.

Это не задание, это личный интерес. Вопрос состоит в том, как использовать значения переменных, будь то строки или числовые переменные, в коде программы, а не сравнение их с чем-то и затем выполнения действий. 
*Пояснение для комментаторов.*
`Не нужно приводить примеры других циклов или способов сравнить значение введенной переменной и в зависимости от её значения выполнять что-то. Нужно именно встроить её значение в код. Например, чтобы использовать это для объявления переменных. Пусть, мне нужно объявить значение переменной, которая будет начинаться с foo_, а закончится введённым с клавиатуры значением и никак иначе.`

Например, мы вводим с клавиатуры несколько переменных типа `String`: `odin`, `test`, `foo`. Заполняем ими некоторый массив `arr`. Также, у нас есть переменные `foo_odin`, `foo_dva`, `foo_tri`, `foo_test`, `foo_foo`. Есть ли способ реализовать обращение к переменным следующим образом:

```
for (String n : arr)
   System.out.println("foo_" + n + " = " + foo_..n)
```

Здесь с помощью `..` я обозначил как бы дополнение имени переменной с помощью другой переменной. Допустим, если у нас есть переменная `foo_odin` и переменная `n` с значением `odin`, то, если обратиться к `foo_..n`, мы вызовем `foo_idin`.

Comment: Использовать reflection коль нет возможности описывать if/else switch/case

Answer (score 1):

Переменные можно хранить в мапе `<String varName, Object o>` и дёргать по имени, которое тоже можно парсить и менять как угодно.

Структуру из кучи if/else/switch/case можно заменить на Enum. У каждого элемента в этом енумчике задать свой символ и переопределить для каждого метод с действием. Тогда можно будет вызывать действие по енуму, а не через кучу условий. Но, имхо, кода будет даже больше, хотя он будет вынесен в отдельное место.

Answer (score 0):

Вычислить строку с математическими знаками можно так:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        String foo = "40+2";
        int a = Integer.parseInt(engine.eval(foo).toString());

        System.out.println(a);
    } 
}
```

Ответ взят отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Я добавил приведение к int.

Comment: Я привёл лишь узкий, конкретный пример, и Ваш ответ также узко на него отвечает, конкретным примером.
Я хотел узнать немного другое.
Или, хотя бы, - есть ли такой же ответ для второго моего примера?

Comment: Ну, этот пример работает со всеми четырьмя арифметическими действиями. Разве Вам не это нужно было? А насчёт второго, почему бы не записать переменные в массив и не выводить по индексу?

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно именно встроить её значение в код. Например, чтобы использовать это для объявления переменных.

Встроить значение переменной в код - это присвоение ее значения для инициализации объявленной переменной. И в чем проблема? Что тут не ясного? Конечно можно использовать значение переменной в коде, в частности, присвоить ее значение другой переменной или в строке конкатенацией добавить ее значение. Или снова не то?

Comment: Нужно, например, дополнить название переменной при её инициализации значением введённой с клавиатуры переменной. Допустим, в начале всегда будет `foo_`, а затем будет следовать то, что мы введём. Вводим test - будет `foo_test`.

Comment: Ни в коем случае. Так нельзя. Так бы и раньше по конкретнее вопрос.

Comment: Имя дается однократно при обьявлении и не может состоять из обрывков строк. И по логике вещей, как можно значению присвоить значение - это нонсенс.

Answer (score 0):

Для обращения к переменным по их имени, введённому с клавиатуры, можно воспользоваться *Java Reflection API*. Вот пример, думаю, разберётесь:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Foo {
    public float  foo_1 = 1.1f;
    public int    foo_2 = 2;
    public String foo_3 = "foo";
    private int   foo_4 = 100;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Foo foo = new Foo();

        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (;;) {
            final String input = in.next();
            if ("q".equals(input))
                break;

            final String fieldName = "foo_" + input;
            try {
                final Field field = foo.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                System.out.println("foo." + fieldName + " = " + field.get(foo));
            }
            catch (final NoSuchFieldException e) {
                System.out.println("No field \"" + fieldName + "\"!");
            }
            catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
                System.out.println("Illegal access to field \"" + fieldName + "\"!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения:

```
1
foo.foo_1 = 1.1
2
foo.foo_2 = 2
3
foo.foo_3 = foo
4
Illegal access to field "foo_4"!
5
No field "foo_5"!
q

Process finished with exit code 0
```